# Python Dictionary to a specific format in .csv

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary in python in this way

```
 my_dict = {'1':['a','b','c'], '2':['d','e','f']}
```

and i want to write a csv file in which it is displayed as it follows

```
1, a b c
2, d e f
```

because it is parsed by another application in this specific format.

Is there any way to it?

Comment: Did you try reading about the `csv` module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way to do it:

```
my_dict = {'1':['a','b','c'], '2':['d','e','f']}

with open('data.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join([("%s, %s" % (k,' '.join(my_dict[k]))) for k in my_dict])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_dict = {'1':['a','b','c'], '2':['d','e','f']}

from operator import  itemgetter
import csv

with open('data.csv','w') as f:
    a = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',', lineterminator='\n')
    for k,v in sorted(my_dict.items(), key=itemgetter(0)):
    a.writerow([k,' ' + ' '.join(v)])

data.csv        
1, a b c
2, d e f
```

Comment: you still missing the space after the comma ;)